# can not update user_sdo_geom_metadata when creating spatial database in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

i was using the oracle 11g and try to create a spatial database, i just copied the sample code from [oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_objrelschema.htm#SPATL486)
but when it comes to update the metadata part, it gave a duplicate entry error, and i tried `delete from user_sdo_geom_metadata` and it didnot give any error, and then tried to insert again, still got the duplicate entry error. I also tried `select * from user_sdo_geom_metadata` but got nothing.
any one have idea why? thanks

THE sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE cola_markets (
mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(32),
shape SDO_GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
1,
'cola_a',
SDO_GEOMETRY(
  2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
  NULL,
  NULL,
  SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3), -- one rectangle (1003 = exterior)
  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7) -- only 2 points needed to
      -- define rectangle (lower left and upper right) with
      -- Cartesian-coordinate data
));

INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata
(TABLE_NAME,
 COLUMN_NAME,
 DIMINFO,
 SRID)
VALUES (
'cola_markets',
'shape',
SDO_DIM_ARRAY(   -- 20X20 grid
SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 20, 0.005),
SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 20, 0.005)
 ),
NULL   -- SRID
);
```

error cause: there are duplicate entries for the give table and column value pair in the user_sdo_geom_metadata view.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure, what does the following show ?

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA;
```

Object names in dictionary views are stored in uppercase. So if you want to remove existing entries from  the spatial metadata you need to do this (notice the uppper case table name):

```
DELETE FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'COLA_MARKETS';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: THE SELECT RESULT NOTHING, 0 ROWS SELECTED, AND THE DELETE ALSO SHOWS 0 ROWS DELETED, BUT WHEN I TRY TO INSERT AGAIN IT GIVES THE DUPLICATE ERROR:

Comment: *Cause:    There are duplicate entries for the given table and column
           value pair in the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view.
*Action:   Check that the specified table and geometry column names
           are correct. There should be only one entry per table, geometry
           column pair in the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view.

Comment: i found out the problem, in the user "MDSYS" there's a table SDO_GEOM_METADATA and a view USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA, my understand is when i insert into USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA, the data should be stored in the view, but in my circumstance, the data is stored in the table, not the view, i have no idea why

Comment: That is the way it is expected to work: when you insert into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view, a trigger on that view automatically inserts a row in the underlying table SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE, and becomes visible in the view. Can you do a SELECT * FROM MDSYS. SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE and show the result ?

Comment: Which user are you running the example in ?

Comment: I created a user myself, and i tried to use the default system user, it worked.

Comment: You mean you used SYSTEM ? Or MDSYS ? Or SYS ? Those are all "system" users. You must leave them alone, and definitely *never* create any user data (tables or otherwise) in any of those. Always use application-specific accounts, i.e. accounts you create yourself.